# Unable to save the file Error in TallyPrime

Tags: xml, tally, tdl

I use below xml request to get "List of Company"

```
<ENVELOPE><HEADER><VERSION>1</VERSION><TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST><TYPE>Data</TYPE><ID>List of Companies</ID></HEADER><BODY><DESC><TDL><TDLMESSAGE><REPORT NAME='List of Companies' ISMODIFY='No' ISFIXED='No' ISINITIALIZE='No' ISOPTION='No' ISINTERNAL='No'><FORMS>List of Companies</FORMS></REPORT><FORM NAME='List of Companies' ISMODIFY='No' ISFIXED='No' ISINITIALIZE='No' ISOPTION='No' ISINTERNAL='No'><TOPPARTS>List of Companies</TOPPARTS><XMLTAG>'List of Companies'</XMLTAG></FORM><PART NAME='List of Companies' ISMODIFY='No' ISFIXED='No' ISINITIALIZE='No' ISOPTION='No' ISINTERNAL='No'><TOPLINES>List of Companies</TOPLINES><REPEAT>List of Companies : Collection of Companies</REPEAT><SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED></PART><LINE NAME='List of Companies' ISMODIFY='No' ISFIXED='No' ISINITIALIZE='No' ISOPTION='No' ISINTERNAL='No'><LEFTFIELDS>Name</LEFTFIELDS><RIGHTFIELDS>ISAGGREGATE</RIGHTFIELDS></LINE><FIELD NAME='Name' ISMODIFY='No' ISFIXED='No' ISINITIALIZE='No' ISOPTION='No' ISINTERNAL='No'><SET>$Name</SET><XMLTAG>'NAME'</XMLTAG></FIELD><FIELD NAME='ISAGGREGATE' ISMODIFY='No' ISFIXED='No' ISINITIALIZE='No' ISOPTION='No' ISINTERNAL='No'><SET>$ISAGGREGATE</SET><XMLTAG>'ISAGGREGATE'</XMLTAG></FIELD><COLLECTION NAME='Collection of Companies' ISMODIFY='No' ISFIXED='No' ISINITIALIZE='No' ISOPTION='No' ISINTERNAL='No'><TYPE>Company</TYPE></COLLECTION></TDLMESSAGE></TDL></DESC></BODY></ENVELOPE>
```

For the above request I get "Unable to save the file" error randomly in Tally Prime.

what is the reason & how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add below xml inside DESC, so that it will respond in XML

else it will pick up the format that is last used

```
<STATICVARIABLES>
   <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
</STATICVARIABLES>
```